# Parsing RSS XML with python django

Tags: python, django, xml, python-3.x, rss

I'm trying to parse 3 different RSS sources, these are the sources.

```
https://www.nba.com/bucks/rss.xml
http://www.espn.com/espn/rss/ncb/news
http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/ProBasketball.xml
```

For the most part the structure of all these three sources are similar, except for the url

I'm trying to parse these into the following Feed object,

```
class Feed(Base):
    title = models.CharField(db_index=True, unique=True, max_length=255)
    link = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255, )
    summary = models.TextField(null=True)
    author = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=512, null=True)
    published = models.DateTimeField()
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

This is the source object,

```
class Source(Base):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255)
    link = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255, unique=True)
```

This is the code that I use to parse,

```
import logging
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests
import maya
from django.utils import timezone
from aggregator.models import Feed


class ParseFeeds:
    @staticmethod
    def parse(source):
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.info("Starting {}".format(source.name))
        root = ET.fromstring(requests.get(source.link).text)
        items = root.findall(".//item")
        for item in items:
            title = ''
            if item.find('title'):
                title = item.find('title').text
            link = ''
            if item.find('link'):
                link = item.find('link').text
            description = ''
            if item.find('description'):
                description = item.find('description').text
            author = ''
            if item.find('author'):
                author = item.find('author').text
            published = timezone.now()
            if item.find('pubDate'):
                published = maya.parse(item.find('pubDate').text).datetime()
            url = ''
            if item.find('enclosure'):
                url = item.find('enclosure').attrib['url']
            if item.find('image'):
                url = item.find('image')
            if not Feed.objects.filter(title=title).exists():
                logger.info("Title:{} Link:{} Summary:{} Author:{} Published:{} Url:{}".format(title, link, description, author, published, url))
                feed = Feed(title=title, link=link, summary=description, author=author, published=published, url=url,
                            source=source)
                feed.save()
                logger.info("Adding {} from {}".format(feed.title, feed.source.name))

        logger.info("Finished {}".format(source.name))
```

While I can parse each of these sources on the python console, the feed object created here ends up with all `None` or default fields.
What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Do your logging statements inside your conditional print?  If not, have you tried logging the title/link/summary/etc before your conditional just to ensure you have data?

Comment: Yes they are all `None`.

Comment: @Rachel I've tried these sources on the python console and they seem to work fine, but when I run this as a management command it fails with all the values being `None`

Comment: So the values are `None` when you read them from your sources?  You're model can't save the data because you're not reading it as expected.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Rachel everything works except that the values are none. The models permit null values so it's fine, it's just not the correct data.

Comment: That's fine.  I was just trying to pinpoint if the problem was that you had data that wasn't being saved, or if you were having problems reading the data.  You mentioned your feed object ends up with all `None` values, so I wasn't sure if the problem was in parsing or saving.  Now I understand.  Have you tried printing `item` immediately, before even trying to parse a title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
for item in items:
    title = ''
    if item.find('title') is not None:    # The "is not None" part is critical here.
        title = item.find('title').text
    # And so on ...
```

If you try in your terminal

```
bool(item.find('title'))            # This is False
item.find('title') is not None      # while this is True
```

Every time you want to check if something is or not is None, use `if something is None` construction.